# Show that $\frac{46!}{48}+1$ is not a power of 47

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The original exercise was:

> Prove that there is no non-negative integers such that $m!+48=48(m+1)^n$

I could type something, but I've stopped at the moment I had to prove that that $\frac{46!}{48}+1$ is not a power of 47.Could anyone help me? I'll post my solution below:

> Assume that there is such $m,n$, This, we must have that $48 \mid m!$, where $m$ must be at least 6. Note that $\frac{6!+48}{48} = 46 \neq 7^n$ and so, $m\geq 7$. By the same way, we have that $m \neq 7$ and we find $m \geq 8$. Note that, in this case, $6 \mid \frac{m!}{48}$, i.e, $$1=6 \wedge \frac{m!}{48}+1 = 1 = 6 \wedge (m+1)^n$$ and, so, $6 \text { and } m+1$ are coprimes.
> If we had $m+1$ compound, then, there is a prime $p >3$, since both $2 \text{ and } 3$ do not divide $m+1$, such that $p \mid m+1$. By the other hand, once $48=2^4.3$, we have that $p \mid m!$, but $p \nmid m!+48$, which is an absurd, since $p \mid m+1$. Then, $m+1$ is prime and, by Wilson's Theorem, we have that $m+1 \mid m!+1$. Using this last argument with $m+1 \mid m!+48$, we reach that $m+1 \mid 47 \Rightarrow m=46$.
> Now, remains to be shown that $\frac{46!}{48}+1$ is not a power of $47$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that
$$
47^n=\frac{46!}{48}+1.
$$
Then, $7\mid 47^n-1$, so $47^n\equiv (-2)^n\equiv 1\pmod 7$. Hence, $6\mid n$. However, it means that
$$
47^6-1\mid 46!
$$
but $47^2-47+1$ divides $47^6-1$ and $47^2-47+1=2163=21\cdot 103$. Thus, $2163\mid 46!$, but $103$ is prime and $103>46$, contradiction.

Comment: (+1) Best solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

$$46!=48(47^k-1)$$

First since $47^{7}\equiv1\pmod{43}$ we know $7\vert k$. (Easy to see by brute force $7$ times)

Next since $47^{40}\equiv1\pmod{41}$ and $47^{2}\equiv35\neq1\pmod{41}$ and $47^{4}\equiv24\neq1\pmod{41}$ and $47^{5}\equiv26\neq1\pmod{41}$ we know at least one of $8$ or $10$ divides $k$.

Either case, $k\geq56$ which implies the right side is much larger than the left side, contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

You could compute $46! \equiv 281 \mod 47^2$, so $46!/48+1$ is not divisible by $47^2$.

Comment: By the way, are there any results about $(p-1)!+1\pmod {p^2}$?

Comment: How did you get $46! \equiv 281 \pmod{47^2}$ without a calculator or computer?

Comment: @NeatMath I confess I didn't do it by hand.

Comment: @richrow Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson_prime).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently $\dfrac {46!}{48}+1 = 47 \times 22115034632797133 \times 361673892624894911 \times 304948016756743701941$, so finding a small prime factor is out of the question.

Alternatively we can note that $\log\left(\dfrac {46!}{48}+1\right) \div \log(47)$ is not an integer.

---

There is also a sneaky way: note that $\dfrac {46!}{48}+1$ ends in $\dots 000001$. We can attempt to find the multiplicative order of $47$ modulo $10^k$ for a managable $k$, say $k=3$.

We have $47 \equiv -1 \pmod 8$; this part is easy.

We have $47 \equiv -3 \pmod {25}$. We also know that if a power of $47^n$ ends in $1$, $n$ must be divisible by $4$; the multiplicative order of $47$ must also divide $\phi(100)=40$, hence it could only be one of $4,8,20,40$. Noting that:

$$(-3)^4 = 81\equiv 6 \pmod {25}$$

$$6^2 = 36 \equiv 11 \pmod {25}$$

we see that it is at least $20$ (which it is indeed). Finally we show that

$$47^{20} < \dfrac {46!}{48}+1 < 47^{40}$$

and we are done. We write:

$$\dfrac {46!}{48}+1 = 3 \times 4 \times \dots \times 23 \times 25 \times \dots \times 46 + 1$$

and we have

$$3 \times 4 \times \dots \times 23 \times 25 \times \dots \times 46 + 1 > (3\times 25) (4 \times 26)\dots (23 \times 45) > 47^{21}$$

$$3 \times 4 \times \dots \times 23 \times 25 \times \dots \times 46 + 1 = (3 \times 10)(4 \times 9)(5\times 8)(6\times 7)\times 11 \times \dots \times 46 + 1 < 47^{39}$$